# ParameterDiscreteValue with multiple records for crytal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

The below code gets the parameter which is to be taken from datatable, i have looped the values for multiple records from that table for the same parameter .
i want that the values should be added and show multiple records (pages),instead it is being overridden and showing only 1 page of crystal report.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            crParameterDiscreteValue2.Value = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[4];//table.Rows[0].ItemArray[4];
            crParameterFieldDefinitions2 = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition2 = crParameterFieldDefinitions["RollNo"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition2.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues2.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue2);
            crParameterFieldDefinition2.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues2);
```

Your help is highly appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is loop through your list of checked items and then keep adding the values to the parameter. Here is a sample that might point you in the right direction.

```
protected void setParameterList(String parameter, ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection selected, Boolean displayValue = false)
    {
        foreach (Infragistics.Win.ValueListItem item in selected)
        {
            ParameterDiscreteValue param = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            if (displayValue)
            {
                param.Value = item.DisplayText;
            }
            else
            {
                param.Value = item.DataValue;
            }
            report.ParameterFields[parameter].CurrentValues.Add(param);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried looping it , took the selected items from dgv in datatable 
can i take all the values from datatables column?